# Life insurance documents sent to wrong e-mail address. What are my options?

Tags: united-kingdom, life-insurance, identity-theft

Some time ago I applied for life insurance online, and to my utmost incredulity (it never happened since I started using the Internet) apparently I misspelled my own e-mail address.

A host of documents, which included personal information (address, phone number, date of birth, etc.), the policy number, and medical history, were sent to the wrong email address. Unfortunately, I have some evidence that such e-mail address is valid, as messages do not bounce back. Whether someone or something actually reads them is much harder to tell.

My medical history cannot be used to blackmail me, as it wouldn't embarrass me if it were to be exposed. I am much more worried about ID theft.

I promptly contacted the life insurance company and asked them to put a "password" on my account, therefore making it much harder for anyone to impersonate me.

Being in the UK, I am considering the CIFAS protected registration (level 0 mark), but I am worried that lazy or incompetent employees, upon seeing a CIFAS mark on my credit report, may click whatever "reject" button they have on their terminal just to do away with me, and avoid having to do any work. In two and a half years from now, I plan on remortgaging. What do you think? Should I get CIFAS protection, and/or what else should I do?

Last, while I am the first to admit I acted like a goof, I would like to know if the life insurance company also acted with negligence in handling my sensitive information. We are in the UK and GDPR still applies. The e-mail address wasn't verified to begin with, and there was no requirement to type it twice. As far as I know the best practice for sensitive documents is not to send them via e-mail, but to let the client download them from a secure website.

Comment: You’re not likely to have a problem, because your personal details have just gone to some random stranger, not been published for all to see. A random stranger is very unlikely to enage in identity theft.

Comment: "The e-mail address wasn't verified to begin with, and there was no requirement to type it twice."  That's the big flaw.  If there **are** problems, this is what you nail the company with.

Comment: I was very quick in at the start of Gmail and got my firstnamelastname email address - and I get bucket loads of email for other “me’s”.  Ultimately, it doesn’t matter what protection the company has in place, some people will just use the wrong email address (I’ve been receiving email for more than a decade for one particular person who refuses to accept he doesn’t have my email address, despite me contacting him via his friends to ask him to stop - I literally have enough info to become him trivially).

Comment: "_I have some evidence that such e-mail address is valid, as messages do not bounce back_" not bouncing is not much of an indication that an email address is real, _especially_ if the typo was before the "@".